# Printing out from paste0() one on the top of another one as character class

Tags: r

I would like to print out values from a vector in a certain way.

Here is the dataset:

```
vars <- c("1234_AS_SA1_PCNS","2345_AS_SA2_UDA", "3823_AS_SA3_CL")
```

I would like to add `,` between the values and print them on the top of each other with a class of character.

I tried this but this did not do the job:

```
paste0(vars, collapse=", ")

[1] "1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, 2345_AS_SA2_UDA, 3823_AS_SA3_CL"
```

I included `collapse = ",\n"` to hit `Return` but that gave me this:

```
[1] "1234_AS_SA1_PCNS,\n2345_AS_SA2_UDA,\n3823_AS_SA3_CL"
```

My desired output is:

```
[1] "1234_AS_SA1_PCNS, 
     2345_AS_SA2_UDA, 
     3823_AS_SA3_CL"
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: If you need the output like printed use `cat` `cat(paste0(vars, collapse=",\n "))`

Comment: The default printing will always show new lines as `\n`. You would need to `cat()` the value to actually make a new line.

Comment: I tried `cat` but the output was not character. Is there a way to convert to the character?

Comment: @amisos55 why do you need it to be in separate lines

Comment: @amisos55 Do you want it to written in a file or is it for a different purpose?

Comment: I am preparing a software input file in R. The default is to put these lines on the top of each other rather than a single line. Otherwise, the software does not recognize the line of code.

Comment: @amisos55 you can `write` it to a file and then you could point to that file?

Comment: I generate a file within `fileConn<-file(paste0()` and then I use `writeLines()` function to write the code, then write out by ` close(fileConn)`. when printed out, R prints those in a single line even though correct punctuations are there. Therefore I had to fix it when I open the software. I would like to fully automate this process.

Comment: I have just tried `writeLines(vars, "text.txt")` and the lines are on top of each other. Do you also need them between quotes?

Comment: And following you r comment, `fileConn <- file("text2.txt");writeLines(vars, fileConn);close(fileConn)` does *exactly* the same.

Answer (score 0):

With the question's data:

```
vars <- c("1234_AS_SA1_PCNS","2345_AS_SA2_UDA", "3823_AS_SA3_CL")
```

Any of the three ways below produces the output file in the picture.
Note that `cat` needs `file` as a named argument, since it follows the dots argument.

```
writeLines(vars, "text1.txt")

fileConn <- file("text2.txt")
writeLines(vars, fileConn)
close(fileConn)

fileConn <- file("text3.txt")
cat(vars, file = fileConn, sep = "\n")
close(fileConn)
```

[image]